# AES-256-GCM Python cryptography vs Rails OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, python-3.x, cryptography, aes-gcm

I'm updating a Python script to use cryptography's [AESGCM primitive](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.AESGCM) so it can interact with a Rails server running OpenSSL's [AES-256-GCM implementation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+-28AEAD-29).

To begin, I'm simulating an encryption using identical message/key/nonce to see if both implementations produce the same output.

#### Python 3

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead import AESGCM
data = b"a secret message"
aad = None
key = b'7\x98\xc1\xdf\x7f}\xea5?\\6\x17\tlT\xed\xa2a\x0fn\x87.(\x0c\xe4;*4\xda\x8fY\xc8'
aesgcm = AESGCM(key)
nonce = b'\x8ch\xbe\xfcR\xeee\xc1g\xd6\x80\xda'
ct = aesgcm.encrypt(nonce, data, aad)
ct: b'\xa8\xda\xdd\xdc\xca\xe8X\x84\xdb\x85\xef\xa6\xa6\x95\x00PN\x1e\xe7\xb0\x88\xae\xddc0\x19_\xae\x7f\xfd\x0c.'
```

#### Rails

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm').encrypt
data = "a secret message".encode('utf-8')
cipher.key = "7\x98\xc1\xdf\x7f}\xea5?\\6\x17\tlT\xed\xa2a\x0fn\x87.(\x0c\xe4;*4\xda\x8fY\xc8"
cipher.iv = "\x8ch\xbe\xfcR\xeee\xc1g\xd6\x80\xda"
encrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
encrypted: "\xA8\xDA\xDD\xDC\xCA\xE8X\x84\xDB\x85\xEF\xA6\xA6\x95\x00P"
tag = cipher.auth_tag
tag: "\xB7B\x84h\xDD\xB7y\xCE\x88\xFDI\x9F\xD3\x13\xC51"
```

From the above examples:

- Rails' `encrypted` is the same as the first part of Python's `ct`.
- Rails' `tag` is not the same as the second part of Python's `ct`.

How do I amend one or both of these processes so they produce the same output?

Answer (score 2):

Just found it - the answer lies in how OpenSSL differentially defines `data` vs `auth_data`.

The OpenSSL docs are a little confusing in the [linked example](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+-28AEAD-29) because they didn't make it clear to me that `data` refers to the message and `auth_data` is additional authenticated data.

In my testing, I had mistakenly set auth_data AND data to 'a secret message', which is why `data` was encrypted consistently but the authenticated data bit at the end was different.

TLDR: `data` is your message; `auth_data` is not encrypted and should be set to `""` if blank.